# is there anything like timestamp(9) in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I just encountered a scenario where I have to load data like :

'2014-12-24 13:59:10:060606066'

in a Teradata table have datatype as Timestamp 
as you can see in millisecond format there are 9 digits , is there any way to load such data 
or Teradata does'nt supports it at all.

for now i have removed last 3 digits made it like '2014-12-24 13:59:10:060606' and loaded in database but I may need to handle it in future.

Comment: Teradata doesn't support more than 6 digits. Where is this data coming from?

Comment: we are getting it from a source flat file (, delimited)
is there any way we can handle this knid of data ?

Comment: You can either remove the extra characters using substring or in TD14 apply `to_timestamp(col, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:FF9')`. In both cases you only get 6 fractional digits. Btw, I meant which source creates data with nanosecond precision.

Comment: they are from message queues .

Comment: Timestamp(6) will get you to milliseconds.  As @dnoeth said, that's as low as Teradata goes.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can accomplish this by storing three fields in your table:

1. `Message_Queue_Timestamp TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL`
2. `Message_Queue_Date DATE NOT NULL`
3. `Message_Queue_Seconds_From_Midnight FLOAT NOT NULL`

Using dnoeth's suggestion to convert the input using `to_timestamp()` to retain a DBA-friendly timestamp in the table. This is `Message_Queue_Timestamp`.

Then split the incoming timestamp into two fields: `Message_Queue_Date` and `Message_Queue_Seconds_From_Midnight`. I was originally going to suggest that the latter be stored as `DECIMAL(14,9)` but then realized as a `FLOAT` formatting/converting it to a `TIME` in Teradata is easier. These two fields allow you to retain the precision of the timestamp that was ingested by the database without having to store the data as a character string.

The conversion of the timestamp to seconds should be fairly straight forward in your ETL processing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob , This is an standing data warehouse and I cant modify Core table structure, but I will definitely try it and get back.